# Does write memory wrong can prove that it may be electrical fault?

Tags: memory, fault

I hear a story that:
A man who new a huge memory and set all of them to be zero
and then read them and find there are some are not zero,so it prove that it may be electrical fault?

Does it right?Why?

Comment: generally a ram test uses 1's, 0's and patterns of 1's and 0's to verify integrity of memory. only using 0 wont find all errors, only some. of course that is very dependend on the type of memory

Comment: @Juhana I don't believe that so I ask here

Comment: @x4rf41 can more be detailed

Comment: @x4rf41   can more be detailed

Comment: @CLS no i cant, first of all, i can barely understand what you want. also, i dont know what kind of memory you are talking about (SRAM,DRAM,Optical,Magnetical, Flash, etc....)

Comment: @x4rf41 It just a story which may just a joke.....can you tell me more about the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but it sounds like you are asking if you set all your memory to zero if it's possible to later read back different values due to an electrical fault?

Yes, that's certainly possible. Power spikes can certainly corrupt memory as well as a lot of other things. Some examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory#Error_detection_and_correction)